# Different between group by() and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1064

when I use mysql I got this error and please can anybody explain me this. what is the different between A, B, C of the following?

```
A) select * from table where a=a group by(b) // this execute & work fine
B) select * from table where a=a group by b,c // this execute * work fine

c) select * from table where a=a group by (b,c) // this is giving an error - error is operand should contain 1 column.
```

In the A it works fine with out errors with brackets, but when I use the same method in C for multiple grouping its not working and gives mentioned error.

why is that? what is the different between group by () & group by in mysql grouping?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

group by (b,c) means you group by the field "b,c", because you use "()".

group by b,c means you group by the field b then group by field c

Comment: no the error explains "operand should contain 1 column". that means if I use group by(b,c) that means mysql identified b and c are two columns. but it says it can't group by two columns if I use (). Thats what my question is, why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

These are equivalent:

```
group by (b), (c)
group by b, c
```

Because the brackets are redundant(they have no effect), but in this:

```
group by (b, c)
```

The brackets are creating a single ordering term from the expression `b, c`, which is not a single value, and `order by` terms must be single-valued.